# Programmatically scroll a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, gridlayoutmanager

I have already used this:

```
mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
```

to programmatically scroll a `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager`.

I was trying to do the same with a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`.

The problem is that scrollToPosition does not really make sense because an item can be in the middle of a line.
Anyway I tried that code and it didn't do anything.

Is there a way to programmatically scroll a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually:

```
mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
```

works.
In my case it wasn't because I was calling it synchronously in the method:

`public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)`

It was enough to post a runnable (without any delay) to the looper of the main thread.

```
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mRecyclerView != null) {
                mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method "scrollVerticallyBy" of GridLayoutManager

```
int scrollVerticallyBy (int dy, 
                RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, 
                RecyclerView.State state)
```

Scroll vertically by dy pixels in screen coordinates and return the distance traveled. The default implementation does nothing and returns 0.

Ref: [scrollVerticallyBy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html#scrollVerticallyBy(int,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Recycler,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State))

Comment: right but that means that I would have to implement the scrolling by myself. I was looking for a bit of support from the implementation of GridLayoutManager

Comment: Yes, maybe there are other solutions but according to reference this is it.